# Using externally_connectable to Send Data from WWW to Chrome Extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm looking to send data from a website to the LocalStorage of a chrome extension.

I've tried the below answer which is what I'm looking for, however it appears to not be functioning at all on Chrome 29 stable. Could anyone advise as to why this may be/tweaks?

Comment: It's not clear why you have issues with sending values to the extension and saving them in local storage. It might be that you didn't ask for permissions on all the sites you liked the ext to work on?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to manage extension's localstorage from a website because of security rules.

But there is a [method](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#external-webpage) that allows you to send message from a website to an extension.

Consequently, you may send your data to extension with this method and get this data on extension's background page then do whatever you want with it (saving to exension's localstorage).

It's really well explained in [DOCs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#external-webpage),

### 1. In your `manifest.json`, you will let your website to allow sending message.

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"]
}
```

### 2. `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` will be available on your website. (javascript)

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("your extension id will be here", 
                           {data: { anyDataKey : "example"}});
```

### 3. In your `background.js` create a message listener for external messages.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.data)
      alert("Hi, there is message from the website");
      var data = request.data;
      // now the data is on your extension side, just save it to extension's localstorage.
  });
```

Comment: I've updated this question as your answer appears to not be functioning in Chrome 29 stable. Are you able to advise on possible causes/tweaks?

Comment: I found out this won't work from an iframe unless you have both the iframe domain and parent page domain in externally_connectable. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/R_wj-r9OQP0

Comment: I found it must to add "externally_connectable": { "ids":["YOU_APP_OR_EXTENSION_ID"] }" into both manifest.json. and seems chrome(tested, M40) does not support to send msg back by "sendResponse" arg.

Answer (score 0):

In order to send data from any webpage into your extension you need to send that data into your extension and in your extension background file you have to receive it using **[runtime.onMessageExternal](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onMessageExternal)**

Yes, @okan-kocyigit answer provide pretty well info on how we can allow our extension to connect and receive data from any external web page. I would just like to update with latest doc link and latest syntax. Please check this latest **[chrome extension doc](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/messaging/#external-webpage)** to get a clear idea.

### How to send data from webpage to your extension

as per the doc You can send any data to your extension by doing like below your webpage's javascript file

```
// The ID of the extension we want to talk to.
var yourExtensionId = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc";

// Make a simple request to send data to your extension:
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(yourExtensionId, {accessToken: "logged user's accessToken"},
   //below callback is optional
   function(response) {
      if (!response.success)
         handleError(url);
});
```

### How to receive above external data from our web page into our extension

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    // console.log(sender) will be from where we sending data
    // console.log(request) data object which we send from our webpage
    if (request.accessToken) {
      // now we have the accessToken from our web page
      // so we can use it in our extension by storing into localStorage of extension 
      chrome.storage.sync.set({accessToken: request.chromeAccessToken}, function() {
        // console.log('accessToken value is set to ' + user.accessToken);
      });        
    }
```

follow this chrome doc link **[runtime.onMessageExternal](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onMessageExternal)** for more details

And please don't forget to add [**externally_connectable**](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/manifest/externally_connectable/#without-externally-connectable) in your manifest.json file to get this running.

```
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://*.yourapp.com/*", "*://yourapp.com//*"]
}
```